# Mysql problem creating and reading db problem

Tags: python, mysql

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True, nullable = False)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(10), unique = True, nullable = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True, nullable = True)
    role = db.Column(db.Integer, unique = True, nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ID: {} Name: {} PN: {} Email: {} Role: {}>".format(self.user_id, self.name, self.phone_number, self.email, self.role)

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
passw = generate_password_hash('123')
db.session.add(User(user_id = 0, name = "User_1", password=passw, role = 0))
db.session.commit()
User.query.all()
```

'''
**On start getting error:**
*C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xE7\xE8\xEC\xE0)' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)*

Comment: Hey Wisd, welcome to SO! Please read up on [writing a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your next question :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a warning not an error.

To get the warning to go away, specify the character set as `utf8mb4`.